# SSRS Subscriptions dont send mail when result is null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a susbcription in SSRS2008 that sends an email with a xls file, is there any way I can "cancel" the mail if the query result of my report is empty?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data driven subscription.  Populate the "TO" field using a query; have the query test to see if the data exists, if so, return the "TO" string.  Otherwise, return NULL.  The subscription will error out and not send anything when there's no data.

Comment: The data-driven suscriptions are created in the Report Manager url ? you know what version of SSRS do i need to use them? I don´t have that option :(